# Dont working prev and next methods at flicking slider

Tags: reactjs

**i have two buttons, but thay are not move slider. maybee anyone have an example?**

```
  <button className="carousel__back-button" onClick={() => flicking.current.prev()}>&nbsp;</button>
  <button className="carousel__next-button" onClick={() => flicking.current.next()}>&nbsp;</button>
```

**----------initial flicking options----------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
    let flicking: React.RefObject<Flicking> = 
React.createRef<Flicking>()

let oprionsFlicking = {
  className: "flicking",
  ref: flicking,
  hanger: "0",
  anchor: "0",
  bound: true,
  gap: 5
}
```

**-----------use here-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
        <StyledDateWrapper>
      <Flicking ref={flicking} {...oprionsFlicking} style={{height: '51px', width: '100%'}}>
          { currentMonthDates.length > 0 && Object.entries(currentMonthDates
          .reduce((a, i) => {
            const normolizeDate = i * 1000;
            const dayNumber = new Date(normolizeDate).getDate()
            const dayWeek = new Date(normolizeDate).getDay()

            return {...a, [dayNumber]: { dayWeek, checked: false }}
          }, {}))
          .map((el: any) => el[0] == checkedDay ? ([...el, el[1].checked = true]) : el)
          .map(([date, day]: any) => {
            const monthIdx = new Date(currentMonth.start ? currentMonth.start * 1000 : new Date()).getMonth();
            const month = monthesMapper[monthIdx]

            return <StyledDateTabWrapper key={date} className="panel">
                 <DateTab 
                  onClick={() => takeDay(date)}
                  selected={day.checked}
                  date={`${date} ${month}`} 
                  day={`${daysInWeek[day.dayWeek - 1] ? daysInWeek[day.dayWeek - 1] : 'Вс'}`} 
                  holiday={daysInWeek[day.dayWeek - 1] ? false : true}
                  theme={PrimaryThemeConfig}/>
              </StyledDateTabWrapper>
            }) }
      </Flicking>
      { renderArrows() }
    </StyledDateWrapper>
```

p.s. react functional component

Comment: I think your code need more clarification. Where you are using it. Where you use the ref

Comment: hi man. updated